# How to handle keyboard.print data from arduino leonardo to android

Tags: android, keyboard, arduino

I have an arduino leonardo connected to an android tablet, the leonardo is measuring temperature and spitting it out using:

```
Keyboard.print(temp);
Keyboard.press(KEY_RETURN);
Keyboard.release(KEY_RETURN);
```

If I open excel on my PC and connect the leonardo it prints the temperature, and then skips to the next cell as the "keyboard's" enter key was pressed.

But how do I handle this data in android?

I want to have a bargraph rise and fall, indicating the temperature. I can draw a line on a canvas using the temp variable as input for the Y coordinate,
but how do I get every new temp value assigned to the coordinate?

I've tried an editText but it doesn't respond to the enter key, the numbers just get stuck behind each other.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found it!

You have to set an OnKeyListener, if this detects a keystroke, and that is "enter" I use the temp as Y coordinate and then clear the editText.

```
myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)   {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)){

            //do stuff

            }
        }
     }
```